# Why my emacs does not display shell's output?

Tags: shell, emacs, heroku

I use emacs23.4 on window xp. So the shell-mode use windows cmd.exe.

I encountered such a problem that If I use the commands which ask for user input（.e.g email, password）, my emacs does not display the request.

I have commented out all configuration in .emacs.

The picture shows the result that I input "heroku login" in emacs and cmd.

[image: The result that I input "heroku login" in emacs and cmd]

Comment: Know that you can start emacs with the `-q` option to load neither ~/.emacs nor default.el. This might be easier than commenting out your configuration.

Comment: may be trying `ansi-term` instead of shell. (press `C-m` for `RET` in ansi-term)

Comment: Thanks. N.N. and kindahero. I try to M-x ansi-term. But I got an error "Spawning child process: invalid argument".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with emacs on Windows: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Sub_002dprocesses.html#index-subprocesses_002c-hanging-when-reading-input-213

Unfortunately, there's no easy work around.  You're best alternative is probably to provide your heroku credentials in a `.netrc` file to avoid being prompted.

Answer (score 0):

setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

seems that there is a workabl but not satisfied answer here :

[printf not printing on console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035075/printf-not-printing-on-console)