# How can see printf(C code) in eclipse console?

Tags: c, eclipse, console, printf, message

I am working with eclipse, jni, c, CentOS6.

I really want to see some logs from C code, but in eclipse console, it does not show printf Message which happens in C.

Is there any way to print C logs in eclipse console?

Comment: You can check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035075/printf-not-printing-on-console for your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ozan Deniz  Thanks for sharing your knowledges. to summarize that link, eclipse has C console problem itself. so if someone print C msg in eclipse console, has to use fprintf(stderr, "")... Thanks again.