# How to read and print the resulting array with fgets and printf("%s")?

Tags: c

I know it is a simple question but I am stuck.The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 1025
#define NUM 64
int main(){
    int mem_size;
    char types[NUM];
    char values[MAX_SIZE];

    fgets(types,NUM,stdin);
    printf("%s",types);
    fgets(values,MAX_SIZE,stdin);
    printf("%s",values);
    scanf("%d",&mem_size);
    printf("%d",mem_size);

    return 0;
}
```

Although I want the results after I type and hit enter,  the flow is: I need to enter all the fgets and scanf stuff and it correctly prints the desired results.
What is the problem? Please help.

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? What does it actually do? What input do you give it?

Comment: @interjacy I want to write someting to console then hit enter and then want to see the what I currently typed.

Comment: Then I suggest running the code you posted above.

Comment: Problem is it shows the results after I enter mem_size altogethger simultaneously,not one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP: "Problem is it shows the results after I enter `mem_size` altogether simultaneously, not one by one"

Some systems to not "flush" the `stdout` output promptly even with a `\n`.  The output that was seen came out just before the program ended, which forced the buffered `stdout` to the console.

Either add `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf()` or change your system's settings (varies with environment) to promptly send `stdout` to the console.

Ref:

[printf not printing on console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035075/printf-not-printing-on-console)

Comment: @Murat Mataracı it was the "Problem is it shows the results ..." comment that made your question sensible.  The post contained the 1) what was done 2) statement about what was wanted but it was _missing_ 3) what happened - the comment fixed that.  Suggest future posts contain 1) the question 2) code 3) data in 4) data out 5) expected result.  Also, after some time - an hour, a day, if an answer works well for you, accept the best one.