# printf in Linux does not work right

Tags: c, linux, printf, fork

```
pid_t pid=fork();
printf("%d\n",pid);
if(pid==0){
     sleep(3);
     printf("!");
}
else  
{   
   printf("@");
   read_routine(clnt_sock,buf);
}
```

On my console, I can see two pid and `!`, but there is no `@`.

And when I delete the statement `read_routine(clnt_sock,buf);`, then I can see `@` on console.

In `read_routine` function, there is just some input statement using `fgets()`.

Are there some secrets of `printf`?

Comment: There some secrets of stdout.  Line-buffering is one of them.

Comment: Dupe to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13035075/694576 and and and?

Comment: `printf` works just fine

Answer (score 3):

Your output is probably buffered.  After the `printf`, you will likely want to `fflush(stdout);`.

Answer (score 2):

Add fflush(stdout) after print and try.