# git bash, how to see progressing printf() while running?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, git-bash

I've installed `mingw64` to use `gcc` in git bash, and I'm programming simple `c` program.
And there are the codes for example

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  printf("hello\n");
  sleep(3);
}
```

when I compile it and run this code `./a.exe` like this
the output comes out when the program is finished not while in progress.
When I use Linux console exactly the same code as above, the `printf()` works and shows on the console
while it is running. I would like the git bash to do the same.
can you help me?

Comment: I experienced some visual problems in git bash too, consider using wsl or powershell

Comment: Two notes: (1) While it's called "git bash", it's just a port of bash to Windows and has nothing to do with Git itself. (2) `printf` in C has nothing to do with bash or any shell.

Comment: Now would perhaps be appropriate to show a screenshot of the shell with code running in it

Comment: You are using the git-bash under windows. So please tag as "git-bash" in the future and not with git and bash separately, as your question has nothing to do with git nor bash. :-)

Comment: Add `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` before the loop or add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13035344/6330106

Comment: If @ElpieKay's hint helps, I'd suspect that the output in git bash is fully buffered, not line buffered. You might like to read the documentation of `setvbuf` (what you should do anyway, to know what you are doing) and try to set `stdout` to line buffered.

Comment: sorry Klaus,, I'll be careful!

Comment: thx for all, answering!!